# Spring Boot application with Spring JPA implementation to COSMOS DB

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, azure-cosmosdb

We have a spring boot application which is using Postgres DB and Spring JPA imlementation.

Now we have decided to move to Azure and cosmos DB. Is there any way we can simply migrate our code from Entity relational DB model to COSMOS DB document model implementation. Do we need to to do full code revamp or can we achieve it with some other technique.

Comment: what made you suddenly switch to cosmos-db, what is the impact on business?

Comment: @silentsudo As we are using Azure, COSMOS DB is the best choice for us to move forward as per the analysis we have done. This is currently in POC phase. Could you suggest any thing on the implementation part ?

Comment: Since you seem to use spring-data-jpa you might be interested in spring-data-cosmosdb https://github.com/Microsoft/spring-data-cosmosdb

Comment: @JensSchauder For this i have to revamp the entire model objects and implementation ..Is there any other way like putting some wrapper class to achieve this

Comment: Not that I know of.

Comment: Cosmos DB is not a relational database, despite it using a SQL-based query language. There is no direct mapping from relational to document, as a plug-n-play type of refactor.